# ASP.Net MVC partial views and jqGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I get the following error message when rendering a partial view with a jGrid on.

"Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$.jgrid.defaults' is null or not an object"

I have included the relevant .js files. I am concerned about the following line in jquery.jqGrid.js

```
var pathtojsfiles = "/Scripts/";
```

All my .js files are under the scripts folder of my project.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<%= this.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/js/jquery.jqGrid.js") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/js/jquery.jqGrid.js") %>
```